# arduino signal pattern matching

Tags: arduino

I have a microphone connected to an analog input of my arduino. This microphone is connected to the +5V via a resistor.

What i want to do is to detect "taps" on the microphone and the user will play a sequence (like a drummer). The arduino have to recognize if this is the good sequence (duration between the taps). But we can have a user which will make the sequence faster.

I do not know where to start. I do not think FFT is a good thing because the speed will be different.

Thanks

Comment: a "tap" is quite a distinctive signal, high amplitude, sharp edges -- if arduino reads the analog input fast enough (I think it does), then maybe just compare the input with some predefined (hard-coded) threshold to detect the signal, without any FFT or complicated processing. Then, do the logic of durations.

Comment: write a routine that works perfectly with button presses, then figure out how to convert the hardware, which should be relatively simple, replacing `if(digitalRead(pin)==hi)` with `if(analogRead(pin)>600)`

Answer (score 0):

Forget FFT. 
Arduino Uno does not have enough memory for this algo... and even if you can make it fit, you will be left with about nothing of memory for your application... Use an analog integrator instead. 
One opamp with a capacitor and a resistor in the feedback between your microfone and the arduino input do the trick. 
When the user taps, the output will go high, and will take quite a while to go low again. You can measure the milliseconds between the time it goes up and the time it goes up again...
A simple state-machine that detects the high peak, init a counter, wait the signal go low, wait it go up again and stop the counter can do this... There are tons of ways of doing this... be creative
I will not give you numbers, because it is the kind of thing that you might have need to tweak yourself based on what you consider a beat, the impedance of your microphone, the reaction time of your arduino...

Comment: Thanks but do you think the opamp is really necessary ?